# Redirect /file to /folder/file using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect from `example.com/file.extension` to `example.com/folder/file.extension`.
I was wondering if this is possible and I do not really know where to go.

The extension can be of any kind for example `.mp3`, `.png` or `.exe`

Edit - I've figured out sort of what I need because it works, but I need to exclude things that shouldn't be rewritten such as php, css, html:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.(.+)$ /folder/$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Compacted title, improved grammar, moved domains to official example domains. Removed superflous information like thank you notices and level of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/file.extension` to `/folder/file.extension` You could  use the following `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/.]+)\.(.+)$ http:// example.com/folder/$1.$2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Is there any way to do this without a redirect but instead a Rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken what was posted and modified it to get my answer.

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+).((txt|png|jpeg|jpg|mp3|mp4|bmp|gif|exe|dmg))$ /folder/$1.$2 [QSA,L]